# Assembly 32bits sum of elements of two vectors

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, visual-c++, x86

I have a problem with sum of elements of two vectors type double which are the same size. Code always returns 0.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    double* tab = new double[n];
    double* tab3 = new double[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        tab[i] = 1;
        tab3[i] = 1;
    }
    double sum;
    __asm {
        mov eax, n; //vector size
        mov edi, tab; //first vector
        mov esi, tab3; //second vector
        fldz;
    l:
        fadd[edi + 8 * eax - 8];
        fadd[esi + 8 * eax - 8];
        dec eax;
        jnz l;
        fstp sum;
    }
    cout << sum;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly i am not on windows, so i had to modify the code to use g++ instead of msvc, but i used intel syntax assembly too. During debugging it turned out that `fadd` instructions had no effect. I fixed it by adding `qword ptr` before the `[edi + 8 * eax - 8]` and `[esi + 8 * eax - 8]` to tell assembler to use pointers to an 8 byte value (since you are using `double` instead of `float`):

```
fadd qword ptr [edi + 8 * eax - 8];
fadd qword ptr [esi + 8 * eax - 8];
```

Comment: The reason `fadd dword ptr [...]` had no effect is that the low 32 bits of `(double)1.0` are all zeros; the whole 52-bit mantissa is zero.  That's the bit-pattern for `0.0f`, so that's what you're adding.  It's unfortunate that some assemblers have a default memory operand-size for `fadd`, instead of requiring you to disambiguate float vs. double.

Comment: @Peter Cordes This is all true, and in fact original code did not want to compile for me under linux using g++ with -masm=intel. I am pretty sure the reason it was not compiling was lack of explicit pointer size (although i may be wrong, as i forgot by now). I also agree with the sentiment about default operand size in assemblers.

Comment: `g++ -masm=intel` is a code-gen option, not affecting `as` options for the `.s` -> `.o` step, only `cc1plus` options for the `.cpp` -> `.s` step.  To use GAS Intel-syntax, normally you put `.intel_syntax noprefix` at the top of the file, although you can pass options to GAS.  Doing that via g++ looks like `g++ -c -m32 -Wa,-msyntax=intel -Wa,-mnaked-reg fadd.s`.  (I always just edit the file instead of checking the `as` man page for those options.)

Comment: GAS in Intel-syntax mode does actually reject `fadd [mem]` as ambiguous.  But in AT&T mode, `fadd` defaults to `fadds` instead of `faddl`.   Recent GAS added a warning for that as well as for integer instructions other than `mov` (such as `inc (%edi)` or `add $1, (%edi)`, which also default to dword operand-size; mov gets rejected as ambiguous).   `Warning: no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; using default for 'fadd'`.  Intel-syntax mode also rejects `inc [edi]` the same way, probably changed in the last year or two along with adding a warning in AT&T mode.

Answer (score 1):

So you are looking for asm for this bit of C code, right? https://godbolt.org/z/vbdfEb94s

```
#include <cstddef>

double add(double *a, double *b, std::size_t len) {
    double sum = 0;
    while (len-- > 0) {
        sum += *a++;
        sum += *b++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I (meaning gcc) come up with this code for 64bit:

```
add(double*, double*, unsigned long):
        xor     eax, eax
        xorps   xmm0, xmm0
.L3:
        cmp     rdx, rax
        je      .L1
        addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdi+rax*8]
        addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi+rax*8]
        inc     rax
        jmp     .L3
.L1:
        ret
```

and this for 32bit i386:

```
add(double*, double*, unsigned int):
        push    ebp
        xor     eax, eax
        fldz
        mov     ebp, esp
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [ebp+12]
.L3:
        cmp     DWORD PTR [ebp+16], eax
        je      .L1
        fadd    QWORD PTR [ecx+eax*8]
        fadd    QWORD PTR [edx+eax*8]
        inc     eax
        jmp     .L3
.L1:
        pop     ebp
        ret
```

Comment: This does `sum += A[i] + B[i]` instead of `sum += A[i]` ; `sum += B[i]`.  So it has twice the performance, but different FP rounding from creating different temporary values.  (Or it would if the inputs weren't all small integers, so the results will be exact.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Changed in the answer and added C source and godbolt link.